# Finding Hidden Elements with an Added Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Asp gridview that I am hiding elements in using a css class. When a row on the grid is selected I have a jQuery function that adds a selected_row class and changes the color. I am trying to find the data for the rows that are selected, and hidden. My function looks like this

```
$(function() {
  $("[id*=MainContent_grvAccounts] td").bind("click", function() {
    var row = $(this).parent();
    $("[id*=MainContent_grvAccounts] tr").each(function() {
      if ($(this)[0] != row[0]) {
        $("td", this).removeClass("selected_row");
      } else {
        var hiddenElements = $("body").find(".hidden-field").not("script");
        console.log(hiddenElements);
        var myElements = Array.from(hiddenElements, element => element.innerHTML);
        console.log(myElements);                                         
      }
    });
    $("td", row).each(function() {
      if (!$(this).hasClass("selected_row")) {
        $(this).addClass("selected_row");
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("selected_row");
      }
    });
  });
```

In the DOM I can see that they have a class name of "hidden-field selected_row".

When I try to filter using jQuery grep my data returns empty. 
I need the `var hiddenElements` to only contain elements with class name hidden-field selected_row

[image]

Comment: `var hiddenElements = $('.hidden-field.selected_row');`. Try that.

Comment: @JM-AGMS not working

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u3n4gqdr/4/ - That's a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
var hiddenElements = row.find(".hidden-field");
```

To get my data.